# Locking console input without screen blanking

Tags: console

I'm looking for a method to lock/disable keyboard input into a text console (tty, no xorg) without blanking the screen. I would like to be able to monitor the on-screen progress of a long-running program (Partclone) without worrying about tampering at the keyboard (Ctrl-C, switching terminals, etc).

I'm aware of `vlock`, but it blanks the screen.

Comment: pull the plug of the keyboard :)

Comment: Do you need the ability to *unlock* the keyboard as well (without rebooting)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question really intrigued me, seemed like a simple request but was tricky to find options beyond the typical `xlock`, `vlock` and `xset` options.

However I believe I've found 2 methods to do this.

#### Method #1 - cat /dev/...

The first method basically consumes /dev/tty0 so nothing else can get through.

```
nohup cat /dev/tty0 > /dev/null &
```

#### Method #2 - disable usbhid module

The second method involves unloading the usbhid kernel module. This will only work if you have a USB keyboard.

```
modprobe -r usbhid
```

#### Method #3 - grub

You can disable all USB devices using the `nousb` parameter to the kernel via Grub.

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-128.1.1.el5 ro root=LABEL=/ console=tty0 console=ttyS1,19200n8 nousb
```

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for. I like method #2 for its simplicity, and you can re-enable input just as easily afterwards. I won't prevent input from a PS/2 keyboard, but it doesn't matter to me since most of my equipment is USB-only.

Comment: Method #1 does indeed consume keyboard input but also tty output. Are there any other ideas on this? (Non USB keyboards.)