# Lock console session

Tags: debian, console, lock

I've set up a no-x/console only system running a minimal install of debian jessie/testing. For this system I need a screen locker to lock the entire session when I'm away. vlock would be appropriate but for some reason it's not in the jessie repo.

Does anyone know why vlock isn't in the jessie repo? What can I use instead?

FYI I'm using tmux.

Comment: @slm I don't think it's a duplicate, it seems he actually just wants to use vlock, but isn't in the repos.

Comment: @slm This is a quite different question. I would not be surprised if it turns out to be a duplicate but not for the question you point at.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - You'd be correct, I remembered mentioning vlock in my A but it's quite a bit different, I'll retract and remove the comment. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75155/locking-console-input-without-screen-blanking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the package from sid (https://packages.debian.org/sid/vlock), it works fine.

Comment: So should I just add the sid repo to my sources list, update and 'apt-get'? Isn't mixing repos a recipe for disaster?

Comment: Not if you set the priority correctly (https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences), but if used incorrectly, bad things will happen indeed. Alternatively, you can just download the package from the page I linked in the answer. The package was last updated somewhere in 2008, so it's pretty safe to assume there won't be any updates you'd miss by not adding the repo.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it's not in the testing repo?

Comment: Nope, best you ask the maintainer (listed on the right on the site). But as mentioned above, there's no risk in running the sid version. This package is the same in all repos and I highly doubt it would be a different version in jessie.

Answer (score 1):

`screen` has a locking function (^A-x) so most probably tmux has one, too.